# pandas dataframe multiplication by column, with index matched

Tags: python, pandas, multiplication

```
df1=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,3),index=list("ABCDEF"),columns=list("XYZ"))
df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,1),index=list("ABCDEF"))
```

I want to multiply each column of df1 with df2, and match by index label. That means:

```
df1["X"]*df2
df1["Y"]*df2
df1["Z"]*df2
```

The output would have the index and columns of df1.

How can I do this? Tried several ways, and it still didn't work...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html) function and multiple `DataFrame` by `Series` (column) select by position with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print(df1.mul(df2.iloc[:,0], axis=0))
          X         Y         Z
A -0.577748  0.299258 -0.021782
B -0.952604  0.024046 -0.276979
C  0.175287  2.507922  0.597935
D -0.002698  0.043514 -0.012256
E -1.598639  0.635508  1.532068
F  0.196783 -0.234017 -0.111166
```

Detail:

```
print(df2.iloc[:, 0])
A   -2.875274
B    1.881634
C    1.369197
D    1.358094
E   -0.024610
F    0.443865
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I want to do this for every column in df1, without specifying the column name, and concatenate the results into a new dataframe that shares the same index and column names with df1.

Comment: This works. But this is actually very close to what I tried. My question is: why I have to use df2.iloc[:,0] rather than df2?

Comment: Because there are different columns names. If change `df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,1),index=list("ABCDEF"), columns=['X'])` and then `print(df1 * df2)` it only match column `X` with `X`. But if need multiple all columns need `Series` from column.

Comment: What if I have: df2=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,2),index=list("ABCDEF"),columns=list("JK")), and I want to have df1*df2 to produce a dataframe with index=list("ABCDEF"), and hierarchy columns=[["XYZ"],["JK"]]?@jezrael

Comment: @edge27 - do you think `print (pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, keys=('a','b')))` ?

Comment: No, not really, I mean multiply the two dataframes by matching index ABCDEF: df1["X"]*df2["J"], df1["X"]*df2["K"], df1["Y"]*df2["J"], df1["Y"]*df2["K"]....then broadcast along axis=1, so that the product dataframe has ABCDEF as index, and a hierarchy column structure with [["XYZ"],["JK"]] @jezrael

Comment: @edge27 - I think I undestand, use `df = pd.concat([df1.mul(df2[x], axis=0) for x in df2.columns], axis=1, keys=df2.columns)`

Comment: Thanks, it works. Again, I was close to this solution, but I didn't understand keys in pd.concat properly.

Comment: @edge  It create first level of Multindex. If omit it, get duplicated columns names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply` to multiply each column in df1 with df2.

```
df1.apply(lambda x: x * df2[0], axis=0)

          X         Y         Z
A -0.437749  0.515611 -0.870987
B  0.105674  1.679020 -0.693983
C  0.055004  0.118673 -0.028035
D  0.704775 -1.786515 -0.982376
E  0.109218 -0.021522 -0.188369
F  1.491816  0.105558 -1.814437
```

Comment: This won't scale well if the number of columns/rows is big.

Comment: I would have thought it would scale fine with rows, since the apply is along columns? Yes many columns would not scale well, but that is an unusual situation and poster gave no indication of scale.